# Building a form dynamically

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a drop down menu, that a user selects a criteria from, based on the criteria a form gets built.

What I am trying to do now is make sure they cannot build the same for twice, so for example, if the users selects appearance from a dropdown, I do not want them to be able to select appearance from the dropdown, while that form is built.

Does that make sense? Currently here is my code,

```
$('img.toggleadd').live({
    click: function() {
        var rowCount = $("#advanced_search > table > tbody > tr").length;

        f(rowCount < 3) {
            $.ajax({
                url: site_url + 'ajax/row/empty',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log($(this));
                    $('#advanced_search table').append(data);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

and the PHP

```
public function row($name) {
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        return $this->load->view('search/rows/'.$name);
    }
}
```

`$name` relates to the name of a view which contains the corresponding form elements for the selected value.

Comment: Well, you can either make the request synchronous (blocking the webpage while it waits), or you can `disable` the `select` elect that clicked and reenable it when the `success` runs, or you can put a blocking logic check in to see if there is a currently working request on that element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Jared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168672/building-a-form-dynamically#comment14650046_11168672) mentioned, the solution could be something as simple as a boolean value indicating whether or not a request is in progress...

Take this code for example -

```
var request_in_progress = false;

$("#selector").on('change',function(){
  if (!request_in_progress){
    request_in_progress = true;
    $.ajax('/path_to_ajax_module.php',{'data':data},function(response){
      // handle the AJAX response
      request_in_progress = false;    // AJAX request complete.      
    },'json');
  }
});
```